# Discovery of Chromecast using Android MediaRouter APIs

Tags: java, android, chromecast, discovery

I'm trying to discover Chromecast device on my network, select it and use for video streaming in a newly launched activity. It all works fine until I exit my "streaming" activity and return to "discovery" activity. I start a new discovery upon return to this activity and this time it is not finding my device (`onRouteAdded()` never called).
I call `mMediaRouter.addCallback(mMediaRouteSelector, mMediaRouterCallback, MediaRouter.CALLBACK_FLAG_PERFORM_ACTIVE_SCAN);`
in `onResume()` and `mMediaRouter.removeCallback(mMediaRouterCallback);` in `onPause()`.
Is there anything else I need to do to restart discovery process? Note that I don't use MediaCast button and handle RouteAdded/Removed and selection manually.
Thanks.